# Deploying additional files with Java Webstart

Tags: java, file, package, java-web-start

I would like do deploy a java webstart application that has to read a default image (.gif) that is part of the distribution from the filesystem. For some reason I cannot package this image in a jar file but have to read it from the filesystem. Is there some way to add this .gif in the  section of the .jnlp in order to get it downloaded to the users filesystem to the same directory where all the jars are downloaded?